# Rails migration - many belongs_to to same table, multiply FKs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

I need some table like this one:

```
uid:integer
pid:integer
predesposition:integer
primary_key(uid,pid)
foreign_key(uid, user(id))
foreign_key(pid, user(id))
```

So, two questions:
1. How can I declare multiply FKs in migration?
2. How can I declare two (or more) columns belonged to same table in migration?

Example:

```
create_table :encounters, :id => false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user, :polymorphic => true
  t.belongs_to :user, :polymorphic => true
  t.integer :predisposition
end
```

Comment: Are you really using mongodb and mongoid? No such migrations are required with mongoid/mongodb. Please correct the tags or reframe the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to refrence other table then follow the concept of foreign key . And wanna to suggest to use full table name instead of uid and pid .

```
create_table :table_name, {:id => false} do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :pid #suppose its procedures table
  t.integer :predesposition
  t.references :user
  t.references :procedure
  t.timestamps
end
execute "ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_id,pid);"
```

Hope that help .

Comment: Hmm.. but pid (partner_id) must be belongs_to user too. It's a problem, because there can't be to "user_id" columnts..

Comment: then don't add into the migration . run separate alter command for that foreign key , just like primary key .

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166613/multiple-foreign-keys-referencing-the-same-table-in-ror