# MYSQL : Multiple Foreign in one column (Rails, SQLite)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am trying to create a table Task that consists two columns which refer to the same table. The following code is generated by rails. When I tried the same code with SQLite everything worked fine. But I don't know why it does not work with Mysql... Hope you can help me!!! Thank you very much

```html
CREATE TABLE `tasks` (`id` int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
`owner_id` int, 
`assignee_id` int, 
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL, 
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,  

INDEX `index_tasks_on_owner_id`  (`owner_id`),  

INDEX `index_tasks_on_assignee_id`  (`assignee_id`), 

CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_877a66d795`
FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`)
  REFERENCES `owners` (`id`), 

CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_0016c50613`
FOREIGN KEY (`assignee_id`)
  REFERENCES `assignees` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Comment: What do the `owners` and `assignees` tables look like?

Comment: see my answer below. Thank you for help! @muistooshort

Comment: (1) That should be added to your question as an edit. (2) I was asking for the schemas of the `owners` and `assignees` tables, not their contents.

Comment: I found a question that describe exactly what i want to achieve : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166613/multiple-foreign-keys-referencing-the-same-table-in-ror?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: But this question is already 6 years old i when i tried their answers it doens't work for MYSQL, but for SQLite in Rails... I hope you can help me. Thanks a lot @muistooshort

Comment: Your first step is to get rid of SQLite and start developing on MySQL (the exact same version and configuration as the MySQL you're deploying on); yes, SQLite is the default and the rumour is that ActiveRecord insulates you from database differences but it doesn't and the default is terrible. Next, check the data types of the `owners.id` and `assigness.id` columns (hence my questions about their schemas) as error 1215 often means that your columns don't have the right types.