# Rails 5 Form does not save correctly when there are two has_one associations of same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

So I want to create a Trip (`HhAttribute`) that has one starting point and a destination. `start` and `destination` are of the model `Location`. My problem is that in my form which consists of nested attributes it is not saved properly, meaning: `start` and `destination` always have the same value.

I already read [Multiple foreign keys referencing the same table in RoR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166613/multiple-foreign-keys-referencing-the-same-table-in-ror) and tried belongs_to in both models but it didn't work when saving because I would need to set `hh_attribute.start.hh_attribute`.

I've also read other questions and this is what I came up with even though nothing in behaviour changed. Before I didn't have the start- and destination-references in the database I'm not sure if I understand all this correctly with primary_keys.

The other attributes save correctly, only start and destination are always the same.

hh_attribute.rb

```
has_one :start, class_name: "Location", dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :hh_attribute
has_one :destination, class_name: "Location", dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :hh_attribute

accepts_nested_attributes_for :start, allow_destroy: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :destination, allow_destroy: true
```

location.rb

```
belongs_to :hh_attribute
```

migrationfile hh_attributes

```
def change
    create_table :hh_attributes do |t|
      t.time :time
      t.integer :lifts
      t.references :simple_post, foreign_key: true
      t.references :start
      t.references :destination
    end
    add_foreign_key :hh_attributes, :locations, column: :start_id, primary_key: :id
    add_foreign_key :hh_attributes, :locations, column: :destination_id, primary_key: :id
  end
```

migrationfile locations

```
  def change
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.string :address
      t.float :latitude
      t.float :longitude
      t.references :hh_attribute, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

nested form:

```
<%= form.fields_for :hh_attribute do |h| %>
  <%= h.fields_for :start do |s| %>
    <%= s.label :address,"Starting Point" %>
    <%= s.text_field :address, class: "form-control" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= h.fields_for :destination do |d| %>
    <%= d.label :address, "Destination" %>
    <%= d.text_field :address, class: "form-control" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Update**

Excerpt of the generated form:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="Trier" name="simple_post[hh_attribute_attributes][start_attributes][address]" id="simple_post_hh_attribute_attributes_start_attributes_address" />

<input type="hidden" value="1" name="simple_post[hh_attribute_attributes][start_attributes][id]" id="simple_post_hh_attribute_attributes_start_attributes_id" />

<input class="form-control" type="text" value="Trier" name="simple_post[hh_attribute_attributes][destination_attributes][address]" id="simple_post_hh_attribute_attributes_destination_attributes_address" />

<input type="hidden" value="1" name="simple_post[hh_attribute_attributes][destination_attributes][id]" id="simple_post_hh_attribute_attributes_destination_attributes_id" />
```

request log:

```
 SimplePost Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "simple_posts".* FROM "simple_posts" WHERE "s
imple_posts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT
 ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction

HhAttribute Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "hh_attributes".* FROM "hh_attributes" WHERE
     "hh_attributes"."simple_post_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["simple_post_id", 4], ["LIMIT",
     1]]

Location Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations
    "."hh_attribute_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["hh_attribute_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      CACHE Location Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "loc
    ations"."hh_attribute_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["hh_attribute_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]

User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT
     ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      SQL (5.0ms)  UPDATE "locations" SET "address" = ?, "latitude" = ?, "longitude"
     = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "locations"."id" = ?  [["address", "Köln"], ["latit
    ude", 50.938361], ["longitude", 6.959974], ["updated_at", "2018-09-27 16:49:29.3
    96327"], ["id", 1]]
```

Comment: can you show the generated html for the form and the request log (to see how params get to the action)?

Comment: @arieljuod I edited my post

Comment: Well I am not great with self joins. But technically Rails cannot figure out which is the start and which is the destination. This is just two records of `location` pointing to one parent `hh_attribute`. There is probably a Rails way to do this. But actually the way I would do this is replacing `location` `start` `destination` by a single inheritance model. Or even just two different models for `start` and `destination` (not very dry though). Or even maybe adding a column `type` to `location` so you can populate it with `start` or `destination`.

Comment: Oh I just see you have migrated some foreign keys: `add_foreign_key :hh_attributes, :locations, column: :start_id, primary_key: :id
    add_foreign_key :hh_attributes, :locations, column: :destination_id, primary_key: :id` I am not sure what you are trying to do here. The foreign key should be stored on the child, not the parent.

Comment: @Maxence you're kind of the right track but its not a self join since you´re not joining the same table. Rather the foreign keys should be on the other side and you need to join the same table twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Place foreign keys on the owning side

The problem here is a fundamental problem with how you have setup the associations. There is no way the associations `has_one :start` and  `has_one :destination` can be properly resolved since they point to the exact same foreign key.

You need to place the foreign key column and belongs_to on the owning side - `hh_attributes`.

First add  the foreign key columns to hh_attributes.

```
class AddStartAndDestinationToHhAttributes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :hh_attributes, :start, foreign_key: { to_table: :locations }
    add_reference :hh_attributes, :location, foreign_key: { to_table: :locations }
  end
end
```

Then remove the `locations.hh_attribute_id` column.

You then want to add the belongs_to association to the correct side:

```
class HhAttribute < ApplicationClass
  belongs_to :start, class_name: 'Location'
  belongs_to :destination, class_name: 'Location'
end
```

### The pains of joining the same table twice

Then setup let setup the inverse assocation. You would think we could just do `has_one :hh_attribute` and be done with it. Nope.

This is actually really messy since we are joining the same table twice and the location can be in either of the foreign key columns:

```
class Location < ApplicationClass
  has_one :hh_attribute_as_start, class_name: 'HhAttribute', foreign_key: 'start_id'
  has_one :hh_attribute_as_destination, class_name: 'HhAttribute', foreign_key: 'destination_id'
  def hh_attribute
    hh_attribute_as_start || hh_attribute_as_destination
  end  
end
```

### STI to the rescue

There is a less messy but more advanced solution which uses *single table inheritance*.

First add a `type` column to `locations`:

```
$ rails g migration AddTypeToLocations type:string:index
```

This column name has a very important role in ActiveRecord. It tells AR which class to instantiate for every row.

Then we create two subclasses of `Location`:

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  # add the common logic here
end

# app/models/locations/start.rb
module Locations
  class Start < Location
    has_one :hh_attribute, class_name: 'HhAttribute',
                           foreign_key: 'start_id'
  end
end

# app/models/locations/destination.rb
module Locations
  class Destination < Location
    has_one :hh_attribute, class_name: 'HhAttribute',
                           foreign_key: 'destination_id'
  end
end
```

Each subclass now has a `has_one :hh_attribute` association pointing to the correct foreign key. We also need to tell `HhAttribute` about our new fancy *STI* setup:

```
class HhAttribute < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :start, class_name: 'Locations::Start'
  belongs_to :destination, class_name: 'Locations::Destination'
  # ...
end
```

The cool part here is that AR will keep track of the types almost magically since we have set it up in the associations.

Comment: This is a pretty common beginners misstake as the semantics of `has_one` and `belongs_to` are somewhat confusing. Use `belongs_to` to place the foreign key on *this* models table.

Comment: Thanks a lot, STI works perfectly and it looks so easy! But now I'm confused why my nested form works even though I didn't change anything. I think I have to figure out in my head when to use belongs_to and has_one.